# jQuery - Get next element, regardless of DOM placing

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I currently have the the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="article-preview">
    <h1><a href="">Title</a></h1>
    <a class="pic-link" title="" href=""><img src="" /></a>
<div/>
```

When the image link or the heading link is hovered, I want to change the color/border-color of both.

I tried to use the `next()` filter:

```
$('.article-preview h1 a').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        color: "#94c4c1"
    }, 10); 
    $(this).next('img').animate({
        borderTopColor: '#94c4c1',
        borderRightColor: '#94c4c1',
        borderBottomColor: '#94c4c1',
        borderLeftColor: '#94c4c1'
    }, 200);
});
$('.article-preview h1 a').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        color: "#000000"
    }, 200);
    $(this).next('img').animate({
        borderTopColor: 'white',
        borderRightColor: 'white',
        borderBottomColor: 'white',
        borderLeftColor: 'white'
    }, 200);

});
$('.article-preview a img').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        color: "#94c4c1"
    }, 10); 
    $(this).parent().find('a:first').animate({
        borderTopColor: '#94c4c1',
        borderRightColor: '#94c4c1',
        borderBottomColor: '#94c4c1',
        borderLeftColor: '#94c4c1'
    }, 200);
});
$('.article-preview h1 a').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        color: "#000000"
    }, 200);
    $(this).parent().find('a:first').animate({
        borderTopColor: 'white',
        borderRightColor: 'white',
        borderBottomColor: 'white',
        borderLeftColor: 'white'
    }, 200);

});
```

This doesn't work, because `next` only looks in the until the end of the heading. Is there a way to search for the next img element (from the selected element, in this case the `<a>` Tag), regardless of the placing in the DOM?

Comment: You stated "When the image link or the heading link is hovered, I want to change the color/border-color of both." This is a bit confusing because the code you display only handles the hover for one of the links.   in addition do you want the border to change around the heading link?

Comment: @John: You are right, this is just one part, I may change the question. I just posted one part because the other function is methodically the same.

Comment: This plugin might be of help: http://techfoobar.com/jquery-next-in-dom/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using

```
$('.article-preview h1 a').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('a').find('img').animate({
        borderTopColor: 'yellow',
        borderRightColor: 'yellow',
        borderBottomColor: 'yellow',
        borderLeftColor: 'yellow'
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: +1 Works fine in my current setting, but it dose not answer the general question.

Comment: Can the element be anywhere within the document or is it anywhere within the `.article-preview` element?

Comment: I wanted to know how to do it anywhere in the document, just out of general curiosity (but I goest in most cases you have a structure like this).

Comment: If it was within the `.article-preview` you could skip the `.next()` and just use `$(this).parent().find('img:first')` not sure if there is a way to do it over the entire document easily.

Comment: So, for example when I want to select the title `<a>` element when hovering on the image, I would use `$(this).parent().find('a:first)`?

Comment: Yes, assuming that the title link is the first link in the `.article-preview`.... Because you're look at the `a` element in the `h1` element you would need to use `.parent()` twice.

Answer (score 4):

You could use this

```
function getNextElement(currElement, className)
{
    var elements = $('.' + className);
    var currentIndex = elements.index(currElement);
    return elements[currentIndex + 1];
}
```

... and add error handling for edge cases

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are sticking with this format, you could use

```
$(this).parent('h1').next('a').find('img').animate({...})
```

As for the ultra general solution, I'm not sure. I'll test and get back to you (I leave this answer as community wiki if anyone wishes to edit this answer to elaborate).

Answer (score 1):

its better to do children instead of find find sometimes doesn't works in IE.

```
$('.article-preview h1 a').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('a').children('img').animate({
        borderTopColor: 'yellow',
        borderRightColor: 'yellow',
        borderBottomColor: 'yellow',
        borderLeftColor: 'yellow'
    }, 200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you search for is an equivalent of [XPath `following` axis](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example17.html) in jQuery. AFAIK it's not supported natively. You can add custom implementation to jQuery:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.nextElementInDom = function(selector) {
        var e = $(this);
        checkNextSubtree: while (true) {
            if (e.next().length) {
                e = e.next();
                while (!e.is(selector)) {
                    if (e.children().first().length) {
                        e = e.children().first();
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        continue checkNextSubtree;
                    }
                }
                return e;
            } else {
                if (e.parent().length) {
                    e = e.parent();
                    continue checkNextSubtree;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Usage:

```
$('.article-preview h1 a').nextElementInDom('img')
```

The implementation traverses remainder of tree after initial element.
It's inspired by [this solution](https://www.arronwoods.com/blog/2011/04/jquery-find-next-element-in-dom-by-selector/) found thanks to Nina's comment. Unlike it, it's based only on primitive operations (next sibling, parent, first child) and not recursive.